# Customizing allowed grant types with OAuthAuthorizationServer

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I'm implementing OAuth 2.0 for a web api. Initially, the only grant type I'd like to allow is "password" for the Resource Owner Password Grant Type. In the future, I may expand to other stock grant types and even build in custom ones. To implement, I've created in my Startup.cs class the below code. I'm not specifying an authorization endpoint, just a token endpoint.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var myOAuthServerProvider = new MyOAuthServerProvider();

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {

            // mark true if you are not on https channel. This should never be true for Production.
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,

            //Enable a 60 minute expiration time.
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),

            // Allows the authorization server to alter the response coming out so it can report a 401.
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,

            // Provider needs to be the custom class that performs our authentication. 
            Provider = myOAuthServerProvider,

            // This specifies the endpoint path where you can generate a token. 
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),

        });
    }
}
```

For the MyOAuthServerProvider class, should I inherit from OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and override specific methods to only allow grant types I want to enable, or should I be instead implementing MyOAuthServerProvider from the IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider interface from the ground up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow only the grant types you want it's enough to inherit from `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`. Then you need to override two methods:

- **ValidateClientAuthentication** - to validate that the origin of the request is a registered `client_id`
- **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials** - to validate provided `username` and `password` when the `grant_type` is set to `password`

For more information here is the documentation of **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials** method:

> Called when a request to the Token endpoint arrives with a "grant_type" of
>   "password". This occurs when the user has provided name and password credentials
>   directly into the client application's user interface, and the client application
>   is using those to acquire an "access_token" and optional "refresh_token".
>   If the web application supports the resource owner credentials grant type
>   it must validate the context.Username and context.Password as appropriate.
>   To issue an access token the context.Validated must be called with a new
>   ticket containing the claims about the resource owner which should be associated
>   with the access token. The application should take appropriate measures to
>   ensure that the endpoint isn’t abused by malicious callers.  The default
>   behavior is to reject this grant type.

Comment: Thank you! Do I also have to override GrantAuthorizationCode, GrantClientCredentials, and GrantCustomExtension to either throw an exception or return something specific to prevent those grant types from being used?

Comment: Never mind, just saw in the docs that the default behavior of these functions are to reject the grant type. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Is there any way to set `grant_type` programmatically rather than passing in API?